# array_unique for arrays inside array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-unique

I need a function like `array_unique` for arrays inside array.

The Case - should be equal, but output "not equal":

```
<?php
$arr=array(array('a',1),array('a',2));
$arr2=array_unique($arr);
if($arr2==$arr){
  echo "equal";
}
else{
  echo "not equal";
}
?>
```

How should the code be changed to get output "equal"?

Comment: Man, this always comes up. Read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), it says "Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays."

Comment: I asking for "like" solution, please read my question

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Hi, like array_unique for arrays inside array."

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should modify your call for `array_unique` to have it include the `SORT_REGULAR` flag.

```
$arr2 = array_unique($arr, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test if the outer array has unique entries, then stringify the inner contents first for a comparison:

```
$arr1 = array_map("serialize", $arr);
$arr2 = array_unique($arr1);
if ($arr2 == $arr1) {
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function array_unique_when_values_are_serializable($main_array) {
    return array_map('unserialize', array_values(array_unique(array_map('serialize', $main_array))));
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. SO exists to teach users, not just answer questions.