# remove duplicate elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have `for cycle` and there I create an array of names from the list, and what I need to do is remove duplicate values, then I get this array:

Array ( [0] => Tod [1] => Admin [2] => Tod )

```
    $c=count($_SESSION['cart']);

$list_array = array();

    for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    $id=$_SESSION['list'][$i]['id'];
    $person=get_person($id);

   $list_array[] = $person;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), which returns a new array without duplicate values.

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
```

**Outputs**

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

[Check it out here.](http://codepad.org/FGa0Vixn)

However, you need to move `$list_array` *outside* of your `for` loop, and use that array in your conditionals like so,

```
$c=count($_SESSION['cart']);

// if this is in the loop, it will get overwritten
$list_array = array(); 

for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
    $id=$_SESSION['list'][$i]['id'];
    $person=get_person($id);

    // originally, you had $users_array in in_array and array_push
    if(!in_array($person, $list_array ))
        $list_array[] = $person;

}
```

Comment: also refer to this: [PHP:: array_unique for arrays inside array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211900/php-array-unique-for-arrays-inside-array)

Comment: I've tried to use this before, but still getting duplicated values

Comment: if I add [0] i'm getting only first letter of the name

Comment: I just realized your mistake.. Huge oversight on our parts.

Comment: if I move `$names_array = array();` out of for cycle when I try print_r it I;m get this: Array()

Comment: I also changed your conditionals.

Comment: It seems that I did as you shown, bet still getting empty array.

Comment: I suggest updating your question with your updated code so we can see the changes you've made.

Comment: Did that, it seems I've made some progressive changes, now I'm able to save array values outside of for cycle.

Comment: Excellent. Now you can either apply the `in_array` in a conditional statement, like I provided above, or use `array_unique` on `$list_array` after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` checks for string, while you are passing an array. Same thing with `array_unique` - its not intended to check for multidimensional arrays. So a hotfix would be

```
$person=get_person($id)[0];
```

Comment: this causes an error.. get_person is a simple function with mysql query then go through for cycle to collect ar results.

`function get_person($id){
  $result=mysql_query("select person from list where id=$id");
  mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  return $row['person'];
 }`

Comment: `return $row['person'][0];` then? I mean if your single $person that is pushed equals to `Array ( [0] => Tod )` then obviously you cant expect a list to be cleaned and checked correctly

Comment: as I have mentioned above i'm also getting only first letter of the name. Its all so messed up... :/