# How can you get unique values from multiple arrays using array_unique?

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

Is there any way to put two or more arrays into the array_unique() function?
If not, is there any other solution to get unique results from multiple arrays?

Comment: merge arrays first, then use `array_unique`

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211900/php-array-unique-for-arrays-inside-array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to the first part of your question is **NO**.

[The array_unique function definition in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#refsect1-function.array-unique-description) states that `array_unique` takes exactly two arguments, one array, and an optional integer that determines the sorting behavior of the function.

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

Rather than take the manual's word for it, here are some test arrays.

```
$one_array      = ['thing', 'another_thing', 'same_thing', 'same_thing'];
$two_arrays     = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'thing', 'same_thing'];
$or_more_arrays = ['same_thing', 1, 2, 3];
```

A couple of test show that the function does work as advertised:

```
$try_it = array_unique($one_array);
```

returns `['thing', 'another_thing', 'same_thing'];`

```
$try_it = array_unique($one_array, $two_arrays);
```

gives you a warning

> Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 2 to be integer, array given

and returns `null`.

```
$try_it = array_unique($one_array, $two_arrays, $or_more_arrays);
```

also gives you a warning

> Warning: array_unique() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

and returns `null`.

---

The answer to the second part of your question is **YES**.

To get unique values using array_unique, you do have to have *one* array of values. You can do this, as u_mulder commented, by using `array_merge` to combine the various input arrays into one before using `array_unique`.

```
$unique = array_unique(array_merge($one_array, $two_arrays, $or_more_arrays));
```

returns

```
['thing', 'another_thing', 'same_thing', 'A', 'B', 'C', 1, 2, 3];
```

If instead of several individual array variables, you have an array of arrays like this:

```
$multi_array_example = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 3, 4], 
    [3, 4, 5],
    [4, 5, 6]
];
```

Then you can unpack the outer array into array merge to flatten it before using `array_unique`.

```
$unique = array_unique(array_merge(...$multi_array_example));
```

Or in older PHP versions (<5.6) before argument unpacking, you can use `array_reduce` with `array_merge`.

```
$unique = array_unique(array_reduce($multi_array_example, 'array_merge', []));
```

returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Thank you " Don't Panic " for your awesome grate complete answer I wish everyone answers like you.Thank you so much.

Comment: This answer is so satisfying and elegantly presented.  Dude.  Thank you.

Comment: @CosetteN It's very nice of you to say so. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

By default, `array_unique()` takes two parameters, the `array`, of type array takes the input array and the second parameter, `sorting` of type int takes the sorting behavior. You can read more on it in the [PHP manual for `array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

But as suggested by @u_mulder, you merge the array first, probably into a temporary array (you can learn how to do that [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)) and then apply the `array_unique` to that temporary array.